# Laravel Foreign Key field name without '_id'

Tags: laravel-5, foreign-keys

I realise Laravel looks for the 'parent_id' field in my child table, but I have two parent fields in the child table.
And I want to name the field differently rather than 'parent_id'.

How can I convey my field name to Laravel while lookig for the FK?

Answer (score 1):

You can supply your *local* and *foreign_key* while you are constructing your relation in your model;

Say your child table structure is like following;

| id | name | parent1_id | parent2_id |

And your parent table is like following;

| id | name | whatever |

```
// in child model
// first relation
public function parent1()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Parent', 'parent1_id', 'id');
}

// second relation
public function parent2()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Parent', 'parent2_id', 'id');
}
```

Example I have given is for *belongsTo* relation type. See method signatures for other relations on [relevant section of Laravel documentation.](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations.html)

Comment: @ Lazysheepherd, It is saying Undefined property: App\Models\Child::$parent1_id,
Though I have 'parent1_id' integer in childs table migration.

Comment: @AarohiKulkarni Are you trying to access it statically? Can you post full error message and line of code produces the error here?